# Selecting variables without tables in stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I will pass some input parameters to stored procedure and do some calculation on tem. Finally I need to retrieve a few variables. I will not use any tables in database.

How to return only variables using stored procedure without any tables in Oracle?

Here is my code.

```
PROCEDURE SP_C3_PSTK_TAKING(
    SCUR                                   IN OUT        CUST_CUR,      
    V_OUTLET                               IN            VARCHAR2,
    V_DATEOF_STOCK_TAKING                  IN            DATE,
    V_PSTK_VALUE                           IN            NUMBER,
    V_PSTK_VALUE_TP_CARDS                  IN            NUMBER,
    V_ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE               IN            NUMBER,
    V_NESCAFE_SHRINKAGE                    IN            NUMBER,
    V_ICE_CUBE_SHRINKAGE                   IN            NUMBER,
    V_TURN_OVER_FOR_THE_PERIOD             IN            NUMBER,
    V_TP_CARD_SALES_FOR_THE_PERIOD         IN            NUMBER,
    V_STOCK_TAKE_RECEIVED_DATE             IN            DATE,
    V_STOCK_TAKE_DONE_BY                   IN            VARCHAR2 ,
    )
IS 
    TMPSTRSQL                               CLOB;
    TMPSTRSQL1                              CLOB;
    V_ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE_PER            NUMBER;
    V_TOTAL_SHORTAGE                        NUMBER;
    V_T_OVER_EXCLUDING_TEL_CARDS            NUMBER;
    V_SHORTAGEPER                           NUMBER;
    V_ALLOWANCE                             NUMBER;
    V_VARIATION                             NUMBER
    OUTLET                                   VARCHAR(100);
    DATEOF_STOCK_TAKING                      DATE;
    PSTK_VALUE                               NUMBER;
    PSTK_VALUE_TP_CARDS                      NUMBER;
    ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE                   NUMBER;
    NESCAFE_SHRINKAGE                        NUMBER;
    ICE_CUBE_SHRINKAGE                       NUMBER;
    TURN_OVER_FOR_THE_PERIOD                 NUMBER;
    TP_CARD_SALES_FOR_THE_PERIOD             NUMBER;
    STOCK_TAKE_RECEIVED_DATE                 DATE;
    STOCK_TAKE_DONE_BY                       VARCHAR(100);




BEGIN
    OUTLET                                  :=    V_OUTLET    ;
    DATEOF_STOCK_TAKING                     :=    V_DATEOF_STOCK_TAKING    ;
    PSTK_VALUE                              :=    V_PSTK_VALUE    ;
    PSTK_VALUE_TP_CARDS                     :=    V_PSTK_VALUE_TP_CARDS    ;
    ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE                  :=    V_ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE    ;
    NESCAFE_SHRINKAGE                       :=    V_NESCAFE_SHRINKAGE    ;
    ICE_CUBE_SHRINKAGE                      :=    V_ICE_CUBE_SHRINKAGE    ;
    TURN_OVER_FOR_THE_PERIOD                :=    V_TURN_OVER_FOR_THE_PERIOD    ;
    TP_CARD_SALES_FOR_THE_PERIOD            :=    V_TP_CARD_SALES_FOR_THE_PERIOD    ;
    STOCK_TAKE_RECEIVED_DATE                :=    V_STOCK_TAKE_RECEIVED_DATE    ;
    STOCK_TAKE_DONE_BY                      :=    V_STOCK_TAKE_DONE_BY    ;

    V_ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE_PER := V_ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE + ((V_ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE/ 100) * 29 ) ;
    V_TOTAL_SHORTAGE :=    V_ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE_PER + V_NESCAFE_SHRINKAGE + V_ICE_CUBE_SHRINKAGE ;
    V_T_OVER_EXCLUDING_TEL_CARDS := V_TURN_OVER_FOR_THE_PERIOD + V_TP_CARD_SALES_FOR_THE_PERIOD ;
    V_SHORTAGEPER := V_TOTAL_SHORTAGE  * 100 / V_T_OVER_EXCLUDING_TEL_CARDS ;
    V_ALLOWANCE := (V_PSTK_VALUE /100 ) * 1 ;      

     TMPSTRSQL := ' ';       


     TMPSTRSQL1 :=    'select V_ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE_PER,V_TOTAL_SHORTAGE,V_T_OVER_EXCLUDING_TEL_CARDS,V_SHORTAGEPER,V_ALLOWANCE from dual';

OPEN SCUR FOR TMPSTRSQL1 || TMPSTRSQL;
END    SP_C3_PSTK_TAKING;
```

Comment: Hi Vijayakumar, Welcome to stack overflow. Please provide the snipped of full code and try to explain the problem in words.

Answer (score 0):

I will pass some input parameters to stored procedure and I will do some calculation on it. Finally I need to retrieve few variables. Here I will not use any tables in database.

[image]

Comment: Please *edit* your question to include additional information.  StackOverflow is not a forum.  So response posts are meant for answers which solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in scope.  In dynamic SQL we pass a string to a ref cursor the string must be runnable in the context of the database engine.  In other words, could we run this query in SQL*Plus?

```
 select V_ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE_PER,  
        V_TOTAL_SHORTAGE,
        V_T_OVER_EXCLUDING_TEL_CARDS,
        V_SHORTAGEPER,
        V_ALLOWANCE 
from dual
```

Clearly not.  DUAL has only one column, DUMMY.  However we can select any number of literals from DUAL.

So what you need to do is turn that string into a projection of literals, like this:

```
 TMPSTRSQL1 := 'select '
               || to_char(v_ACTUAL_STOCK_SHRINKAGE_PER) ||','  
               || to_char(v_TOTAL_SHORTAGE) ||','
               || to_char(v_T_OVER_EXCLUDING_TEL_CARDS) ||','
               || to_char(v_SHORTAGEPER) ||','
               || to_char(v_ALLOWANCE) ||
        ' from dual';

    OPEN SCUR FOR TMPSTRSQL1 || TMPSTRSQL;
END    SP_C3_PSTK_TAKING;
```